# Why is the __str__ method printing the nodes in an recursive way in a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Just wondering what's the correct way of showing the next node in the `__str__` method. See the following code and the results. It looks like there's some built-in recursive nature chaining the `__str__` methods for each node in the list. Could anyone explain why and how I can make it behave normally, like only printing the next node's address. Thanks.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
    def __str__(self):
        return "Node {}, next is {}".format(self.val, self.next)

a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
c = Node(3)
a.next = b
b.next = c
print(a)
Node 1, next is Node 2, next is Node 3, next is None
```

Comment: Why should `print(a)` and `format(self.next)` do two different things?

Comment: When you pass `self.next` to `format`, you're telling it to insert a string representation of `self.next` into the result string. Hey, look, `self.next` has a `__str__` method for getting a string representation of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is printing all the nodes is because .format convert each input into a string before concatenating it. To do this, it calls the `__str__` method of the next node and the cycle continues.

There are two options to get it to act the way you want. In the `__str__` method you can call the `__repr__`, `!r`, or you can get the memory location manually using id and format it any way you want.

```
return "Node {}, next is {!r}".format(self.val, self.next)
# or
return "Node {}, next is <__main__.Node object at {}>".format(self.val, hex(id(self.next)))
```

Both of these result in the same output:

```
Node 1, next is <__main__.Node object at 0x1005d7fd0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing `self.next`'s `str` representation, try printing its `repr` instead:

```
    return "Node {}, next is {!r}".format(self.val, self.next)
```

Result:

```
Node 1, next is <__main__.Node object at 0x7f9f10066630>
```